# jQuery - How to PUT JSON via Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to put some JSON formatted data via Ajax with [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) to a server. My code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: myURL,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {"data": "mydata"}
});
```

But on the server-side, I receive a `data=mydata` string, instead of the expected JSON. [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) tells me the same.

Where is the error?

Comment: What are you using on the server-side?

Comment: I use Couchdb which expects JSON.

Comment: AJAX PUT *is* available in all major browser. HTTP PUT isn't. So in this case, it's fine (recommended, even) to use PUT.

Comment: Adding the option **dataType: "json"**, might help you out here.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I think the data needs to be a String. Objects are converted to query strings which is what you are seeing here.

You can use the `JSON.stringify(obj)` method to convert your Object to a String. The code for the  JSON object is available from: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js.

Alternately, just pass the code you are using to create the object as a literal String, but I imagine this is just an example and you'll want to encode some object you've already created.

Comment: This is the way @Juri should go if he wants JSON on the server. I use the json2.js library all the time and it works great.

Comment: would be nice if jQuery would stringify the data, just as it does with POST.

Answer (score 32):

If you always have to send JSON in your application, then you can just execute this somewhere in your init and then use default `$.ajax` call as in your example, and it will always serialize as a JSON string instead of the Ajax default query string.

Here I use the JSON object mentioned above:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    contentType : 'application/json',
    processData : false
});
$.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    if (options.data){
        options.data=JSON.stringify(options.data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//url: this is a reference to the XML, where you need to define the mapping.
//<entry key="/getEmpDetails/transEfileGenerate.app">
//<bean class="com.adp.ems.framework.spring.MappingItem" p:delegate-ref="efilePageDelegate"
//p:action="passJSONObjectAndGetWebServiceOutput" />

//str1 is the input JSON that you need to pass... Ajax will automatically take care to get the response.
//</entry>

var kw = {
    url : "getEmpDetails/transEfileGenerate.app",
    timeout : 30000,
    handleAs : "json",
    sync: false,
    putData : str1,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
    load : function(result) {
},
```