# Send JSON to the server using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I have the need to send an array of ID's to my server-side in the form of a JSON Object.I am using a dropdownlist where multiple values can be selected to do an action with them.

To get them in an array, I've used:

```
var selectedArray = [];

            var selectObj = document.getElementById('addedList');
            var i=0;
            var count=0;
            for(i=0;i<selectObj.options.length;i++){
                selectedArray[count] = selectObj.options[i].value;
                count++;
            }
```

Now the question is, I need to get those ID's to the server.
I've always thought of sending it like a JSON object, since it has a variable amount of parameters. As far as I found out, you can convert a JS object to JSON.

**Now I do have a few questions:**

Could you give me an example of how to convert it? There seem to be a million ways, one of them being `JSON.stringify(jsObj);`. My object would simply consist of an array of values. As far as I know this would be an example:

```
{ array : ["value1","value2","value3"] }
```

Another question is:
How can I send this using jQuery? Can I send a JSON object to the server using $.getJSON? (This uses $.GET under the hood), or do I need to use $.POST ?

Now I've just been trying, but can't get it out...

**$.getJSON code**

```
        $.getJSON("removerequest.htm",{ ids: JSON.stringify(selectedArray) }, function(data){
            $('#removerequestdiv').text('');

            $('#removerequestdiv').append('<select name="addedList">');
            for(var index in data){
                $('#removerequestdiv').append('<option value="' + data[index].id + '">' + data[index].voornaam + data[index].familienaam + '</option>');
            }
            $('#removerequestdiv').append('</select>');
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery: How to PUT JSON via Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749272/jquery-how-to-put-json-via-ajax)

Comment: getJSON only grabs a file with json data in it. You need to use some form of post. Theres ajax and post. There is also a json parameter which i believe you can use to send the data. can't remember if this is only used to tell that the return value is json format.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `$.getJSON()` routine is for **fetching** JSON-encoded content **from** the server. Your problem is the opposite: you want to send it **to** the server.

You should understand the terminology here.  There's no such thing really as a "JSON object" in Javascript. It's just a Javascript object of some sort, and there's nothing special about it in that sense. What you want to do is *serialize* the Javascript object into a single **string**.  That string is your parameter you'll send to the server, and the server will *deserialize* that string back into an object (in the context of whatever language your server code is using).

Thus, when you call `JSON.stringify(obj)`, what you get is just a string. Passing such a string back to the server is no different than passing any other string; it's just a parameter. Use `$.post()` to post it, or you can even just stuff it into the value of a simple form input element and post a form the old-fashioned way.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up a lot! Is it possible to send JSON to the server and as well receive JSON with $.post()?

Comment: The response sent back by the server is passed in to the handler function you give to `$.post()`, and that can be whatever you want - it's up to the server software. If your server prepares a response and serializes it as a JSON-encoded string, and sends that back, then your Javascript code can just parse it with the JSON2 library.

Comment: Great answer. Clear and concise +1