# How can I send JSON data to server

Tags: jquery, json, http-post

Well, here is the story:

I have some data need to send to server, but they should turned into JSON dataType first.

I made such ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
       url: url, // the url I want to post to.
       type: 'POST',
       contenttype:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       beforeSend: //some HTTP basic auth stuff
       data: {
          name:'test',
          key:'foo',
          key2:'bar'
       },
       dataType:'JSON'
});
```

basically I'm expecting the data I send to server was:

```
[name:test,key:foo,key2:bar]
```

but what I've got was:

```
name=test&key=foo&key2=bar
```

What did I missing? How can I get those data into JSON?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send JSON to the server using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118226/send-json-to-the-server-using-jquery)

Answer (score 23):

```
 var data = {'bob':'foo','paul':'dog'};
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: 'POST',
   contentType:'application/json',
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   dataType:'json'
 });
```

/**  Added **/

The above does not do anything with the response from the server if you need to do something then a callback will be called when the server has responded.

```
 var data = {'bob':'foo','paul':'dog'};
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: 'POST',
   contentType:'application/json',
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   dataType:'json',
   success: function(data){
     //On ajax success do this
     alert(data);
      },
   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      //On error do this
        if (xhr.status == 200) {

            alert(ajaxOptions);
        }
        else {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: Does this post a response? Or perhaps a better question, is there a way to post without dealing with a response; like kind of like a stream with just one packet

Comment: This does not handle any returned response from the server.

Comment: Thanks, and would $.post be better then, if all I want to do is send a request with some data; and not care about the return?

Comment: $.post is just a shortened version of $.ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) so neither is 'better' $.post has a callback function for return of data too. I like to use $.ajax just because I always have.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem. You can't send an object as "data", you need to stringify the object. Try this instead, with your object stringified:

```
$.ajax({
       url: url,
       type: 'POST',
       contentType:'application/json',
       data: '{
          name:"test",
          key:"foo",
          key2:"bar"
       }',
       dataType:'json'
});
```

Comment: I've seen this too, but I've seen examples that show it like this: data: {name: 'test', key: 'foo', key2: 'bar'}. It fails every time when I try to code it like that

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/05/postjson-for-jquery/

Its a lot shorter:

```
$.post(url, data, function(response) {
    // Do something with the response
}, 'json');
```

Comment: I love this way. $.ajax is more for low level.

Comment: Link is dead, but the current version of jQuery provides an equivalent in any case, with some error handling niceness: see [the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

Also, is necesary can create a parameter and assign the value with JSON.stringify

```
....
data: "jsonString="+JSON.stringify(data),
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree the data must be converted into a JSON string, not only to agree with the `dataType` and `contentType` setup but more importantly, to satisfy the server.

```
data: JSON.stringify(data),
dataType:'json'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to send JSON data to the server

### 1. Using Ajax

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
var url  = '<?php echo $url ?>';
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert(jsonObj.encPassword);
    },
    failure: function(errorMsg) {
        alert(errorMsg);
    }
});
```

### 2. Using Curl

```
<?php
$content = json_encode($data);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //curl error SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK

$result     = curl_exec($curl);
$response   = json_decode($result);
var_dump($response);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

### 3. Using Streams

```
<?php
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => json_encode( $data ),
        'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                    "Accept: application/json\r\n"
      )
);

$context     = stream_context_create($options);
$result      = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$response    = json_decode($result);
var_dump($response);
```

### 4. Raw HTTP Post

Using Zend Framework’s HTTP client: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.advanced.html#zend.http.client.raw_post_data

```
$json = json_encode($data);
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($url);
$client->setRawData($json, 'application/json')->request('POST');
var_dump($client->request()->getBody());
```

SOURCE:- https://blog.magepsycho.com/sending-json-data-remote-server/

Answer (score -3):

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Comment: To be more clear, this answer means that you have incorrectly capitalized your `dataType` value. String comparisons are case-sensitive, and jQuery only tests for `"json"`, not `"JSON"`.

Comment: `dataType` is used for the data that is returned by the response and not for the posting.