# how to send json data to server using ajax

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

refer.jvmhost.net/refer247/registration, this is my url,i have to fetch request to this url  like user details and should get the appropriate response in `json` format with status n error if it contains  ..dont give me android code..

this is `html` page.

```
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="json2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="c">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-inset="true" class="paddingRitLft" data-theme="c">
            <div data-role="content" data-inset="true"> <a href="index.html" data-direction="reverse"><img src="images/logo_hdpi.png"/></a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
            <form name="form" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
                <div class="logInner">
                    <div class="logM">Already have an account?</div>
                    <div class="grouped insert refb">
                        <div class="ref first">
                            <div class="input inputWrapper">
                                <input type="text" data-corners="false" class="inputrefer" placeholder="Userid" name="userid" id="userid" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="input inputWrapper">
                                <input type="password" data-corners="false" class="inputrefer" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" />
                            </div>  <a href="dash.html" rel="external" style="text-decoration: none;"><input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit" onclick="json2()"></a>

                            <p><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Forgot Password</a>

                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="logM">New user? Create refer Account</div>
                    <input type="button" class="btnsgreen" value="Sign Up! its FREE" class="inputrefer" data-corners="false" data-theme="c" />
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p style="text-align: center;">&#169; refer247 2013</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

this is json2.js

```
function json2()
    {
    var json1={"username":document.getElementById('userid').value,
               "password":document.getElementById('password').value, 
              };
    //var parsed = jsonString.evalJSON( true );
    alert(json1["username"]);
    alert(json1["password"]);
};
```

so tell me how to send the json data to that url n obtain some response like if email
id is already exist if u registering with that id ..then give some error
like email id already exist n if registerd succesfully then give respone like registerd successfully and status msg..200 okk...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342926/how-can-i-send-json-data-to-server

Comment: $.ajax({
   url: "refer.jvmhost.net/refer247/registration",
   type: 'POST',
   contentType:'application/json',
   data: JSON.stringify(json1),
   dataType:'json'
 });
 success: function(json1){
            console.log("Success: "+json1.userid);
        },
        error:function(json1){
            console.log("Error: "+json1);
   
        };
  };this is ajax code..may be it cotains some error..but i m not getting..so pls find n correcct me

Answer (score 5):

You can use ajax to post json data to specified url/controller method. In the below sample I am posting an json object. You can also pass each parameter separately.

```
var objectData =
         {
             Username: document.getElementById('userid').value,
             Password: document.getElementById('password').value                
         };

var objectDataString = JSON.stringify(objectData);

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "your url with method that accpects the data",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                o: objectDataString
            },
            success: function (data) {
               alert('Success');

            },
            error: function () {
             alert('Error');
            }
        });
```

And your method can have only one parameter of string type.

```
     [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult YourMethod(string o)
    {
      var saveObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DestinationClass>(o);
     }
```

Comment: there is no need for setting the dataType to json unless the server responds with json.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlToProcess,
    type: httpMethod,
    dataType: 'json',
    data:json1,
    success: function (data, status) {
        var fn = window[successCallback];
        fn(data, callbackArgs);
    },
    error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
       alert("error");
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function addProductById(pId,pMqty){
            $.getJSON("addtocart?pid=" + pId + "&minqty="+ pMqty +"&rand=" + Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1), function(json) {
                alert(json.msg);
            });
        }
```

Here is a simple example, which will call on `button click` or `onclick` event and call `addtocart servlet` and passes 2 argument with it i.e. `pId and pMqty`.

and after successful completion it return message in alert which is set in that `servle`t in `json`.

Answer (score -1):

```
var json1={"username":document.getElementById('userid').value,
               "password":document.getElementById('password').value, 
};

$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/file.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',//no need for setting this to JSON if you don't receive a json response.
    data: {param1: json1},
})
.done(function(response) {
    console.log("success");
    alert(response);
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```

on the server you can receive you json and decode it like so:

```
$myjson=json_decode($_POST['param1']);
```

Comment: Read the question: "should get the appropriate **response in json format**". Also from the comment: "contentType:'application/json'", so the sever expects JSON as well. And why do you think the OP uses PHP on the server?