# How to encode data on html to json and send to a server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Now I get a set of RESTful API, now I want to send a post request to the server by using the APIs.

The format of this post API is like that:

```
header : "Content-type: application/json" 
method: POST 
body : {"key1": value1, "key2": value2, ...}
```

I want to put some input widget on the html page to let user input all the values, and put a button to submit this request.

My question is that:

How to get all the values and encode them in a JSON format data, and send this request with the header I mentioned and the JSON data to the server? The server will return some messages after processing the request, how to get the message and display in Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: jQuery `$ajax.` call should do everything you need...Examples are everywhere!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send JSON to the server using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118226/send-json-to-the-server-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//
//  try
//
$.ajax(
    {
        url   : "http://a.domain.co/",
        type  : "post",
        data  : {
            body:JSON.stringify( $.serializeArray( $FORM ) )
        },
        contentType : "application/json"
    }
).done( doStuff );
//
```