# Rails' wrap_parameters is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `wrap_parameters format: [:json]` in `wrap_parameters.rb`. I post to the server with `jQuery.post('photos', {name: 'flower'});`. In `photos#create`, `params` is

```
{"name"=>"flower", "controller"=>"photos", "action"=>"create"}
```

But I am expecting

```
{"name"=>"flower", "controller"=>"photos", "action"=>"create", "photos"=>{"name"=>"flower"}}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `jQuery.post('photos', {name: 'flower'});` call posts params as 'standard' form (application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data), not json. So `wrap_parameters format: [:json]` does not work.

Try to remove `format: [:json]` or post json data, something like

```
$.ajax({
  url:'photos',
  type:"POST",
  data:JSON.stringify({name: 'flower'}),
  contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(){
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: Works! And my final solution is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6828157/312483)

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform your post request with the header "Content-Type": "application/json".