# Strange behavior in calling $.ajax with PUT verb

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I call $.ajax like this :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'PUT',
  url: model.url(),
  data: {task: {assigned_to: selected()}},
  contentType: 'application/json'
})
```

`selected()` returns an array

it sends request with this payload `task%5Bassigned_to%5D%5B%5D=524eda6b421aa91f4e000003&task%5Bassigned_to%5D%5B%5D=524ee37c421aa91ca9000008` and it's wrong! Must send json but it's not json, my rails server can't handle that (Rails MultiJSON).

I tested on chrome and firefox (both on latest stable version).

Any help is really appreciated.

**Edit**

If I first `JSON.stringify` data it works fine but that's not a good solution at all, and also `$.ajax` works in other methods!

Comment: This question is same issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/1749272/1482780

Comment: Problem will be solved if I set `processData: false` in ajax params. btw why jquery doing that?! why there's an always non-default option in ajax? there must be better solution I think!

Comment: might want to checkout out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410810/rails-not-decoding-json-from-jquery-correctly-array-becoming-a-hash-with-intege

seems to work for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try with some **double** quotes :

```
data: {"task": {"assigned_to": selected()}}
```

Or define your data outside and assign it like this :

```
var dataMap = {"task": {"assigned_to": selected()}};
```

and then :

```
$.ajax({
type: 'PUT',
url: model.url(),
data: dataMap,
contentType: 'application/json'
})
```

Comment: still get error. data and dataMap is exact same (compared with `==`).

Comment: @KiTO Try with double quotes, sorry