# How to set and pass Parameter to the server in sapui5

Tags: parameters, combobox, sapui5

ComboBox ,code in view.xml

```
<ComboBox id="FiscalYearComboBox" width='100%'
                    items="{
                        path: '/FiscalYearSet',
                        sorter: { path: 'FiscalYearID' }
                      }">
                    <core:Item key="{FiscalYearID}" text="{FiscalYearNum}" />
                </ComboBox>
```

controller.js

I have been learning sapui5 less than a month. and I donot know how to send the value in Combobox to the server.

Comment: If I got your question right Ajax is probably what you´re looking for. In your controller you can create Ajax requests to the server as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1749272/1969374

Comment: No, I guess the user input has to be captured..

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using `selectionChange` in **XML view**

```
<ComboBox id="FiscalYearComboBox" width='100%' selectionChange="handleSelectionChange"
     items="{
      path: '/FiscalYearSet',
      sorter: { path: 'FiscalYearID' }
      }">
     core:Item key="{FiscalYearID}" text="{FiscalYearNum}" />
</ComboBox>
```

then in **controller.js**

```
handleSelectionChange ; function(){
  var oSelectedItem = this.byId("handleSelectionChange").getSelectedItem();
  oSelectedItem.getValue();
}
```

you can send this value to your backend server using [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1749272/1969374) call as mentioned by @Tim Gerlach

}