# Q:500 (Internal Server Error) at $http put?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to change a title to a string ("end" for example). This is my controller:

```
.controller("changeTitleCtrl",function($http, $scope) {
  $scope.setInEnd = function(value) {
  $http.put('/api/put', { 'title': "End" }).success(function() {
      alert("Works")
      location.reload();
  }).error(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
    };
})
```

And this is my html

```
<div ng-controller="changeTitleCtrl">
   <h1>{{task.title}}</h1>
   <p>{{task.content}}</p>
   <button ng-click="setInEnd(task.id)">SetInEnd</button>
</div>
```

I'm recieving a message "500 (Internal Server Error)" and alert("error"). What I am supposed to do now.

Comment: you don't need the question mark in the end of the resource url. Angular will append it: $http.put('/api/put', { 'title': "End" })

Comment: Well in fact i don't. I write exactly as you said. The result is still the same

Comment: You're sending a value 'setInEnd(task.id)', but it doesn't look like you're using it anywhere. Is this intentional? Perhaps you are sending the wrong information, or your server is expecting something different?

Comment: I even try like this <button ng-click="setInEnd(task.id)" class="btn btn-primary>Set In End </button> Idk if this is the same or no but i will try now make the values similar.

Comment: Is it correct there is no `;`after the alert?

Comment: What are you supposed to do now? Look at the server logs to see what code is failing and why. That should give you a clue as to what is wrong with the client code. I don't think we can even answer your question as is: you don't say what the server is or show the server code that is blowing up.

Comment: Receiving an error 500 isn't exactly proving your code is wrong, unless you have succeeded your request with other means like e.g. using curl

Comment: I can hardly understand how the hell has there been this much of a conversation going on before reaching @SunilD.'s comment. Voting to close as soon as the OP has read that an Internal Server Error is triggered by an internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely an error in the data type being sent.

> The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note:
>   Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used
>   here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

This link may also be useful: [jquery - how to put json via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749272/jquery-how-to-put-json-via-ajax)